# How to solve this issue?

Tags: java

```
static String user="sa",password="root";
static String url="jdbc:sqlserver://GEETHAM31-PC:1433//SQLEXPRESS";
DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I just used the above url, password and driver to connect with microsoft sql server 2008 r2 database, but i get the following error.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number
>   1433//SQLEXPRESS is not valid.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:580)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   application.ServerConnection.main(ServerConnection.java:20)

Comment: You must have port number 1433 assigned to something else.

Comment: Are you sure the DataBase is running on port 1433? try to confirm this

Comment: Can you recheck the url, looks like it included the database name with port itself. Maybe the jdbc url is not correct.

Comment: Check that port number 1433 isnt already assigned to another process:

You can use "netstat" to check if 1433 is available or not.

Type netstat -anp | find "port number" into cmd prompt. If port 1433 is assigned to something else it will list the PID for that process.

Comment: http://razorsql.com/docs/support_sqlserver_express.html

Comment: Reading the exception give you a tip "_The port number 1433//SQLEXPRESS is not valid_". `1433//SQLEXPRESS` is a strange port value. You should start by check the url syntax

Answer (score 1):

jdbc URL must look like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://{computer-name}\\SQLEXPRESS:1433
```

Comment: The full explanation is here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Comment: After trying your suggestion i found this error                                       com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host GEETHAM31-PC, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

Comment: @sureshv You are sure the sqlexpress Server is running and listen on port 1433?